# Display only nodes with particular taxonomy terms in Drupal

Tags: javascript, html, string, wordpress, replace

There is a drupal site that I need to modify. It has been set up and programmed by others with some custom code. They assign some taxonomy terms to every user (custom made with a checkbox menu in the user edit page)
But when a user searches the site , he finds nodes of every taxonomy term and not only his own taxonomy terms...

Is there a way that I can put a filter on the search result that limits the output to only nodes that have these taxonomy id's that this user has?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself so hopefully I can help others with that.
I did it with the hook_query_alter() instead of trying to get a new filter.

```
function myownmodulename_query_alter(&$query) {

    //check if it is a search query, so we look for a table called seach_index
    $is_search = FALSE;
    foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
        if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
        $is_search = TRUE;
        }
    }

  if ($is_search) {

            // in my case: I want all the currently available taxonomy id's that have a vid=4
            $selection_of_tids = array('SELECT * FROM taxonomy_term_data WHERE vid = 4')->fetchCol('tid');          

            // Join some relevant tables if needed - in my case I needed these 2:
            // join table nodes and taxonomy_index on their node id "nid" column
            $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid'); 
            // join that new joined table again with the taxonomy_term_data table on their taxonomy id "tid" column
            $query->join('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ti.tid = ttd.tid');

            // add your new AND condition to the existing query
            // so i want nodes with particular tid's ($selection_of_tids that again have vid=4)
            $query->condition('ti.tid', $selection_of_tids, 'IN'); 

            //for an extra AND condition (x OR y) use or add it this way:
            $query->condition(db_or()->condition('ti.tid', 1, '=')->condition('ti.tid', 2, '='));

            // for testing purposes: use "print" query instead of "var_dump" 
            // and you can always check the search query in your website on top
            echo "<pre>"; print $query;  echo "</pre>";

    }

}
```